# Ui Path Automation with anchors

Tags: automation, uipath

I am creating an automation that filters through an excel sheet and copies a value from one of the cells after filtering. Once I use a click function to click onto the filter tab, then I use a type into and a hardcoded value that the user inserts by typing into a text box. But the username changes each time the sheet is filtered. What function would I use or how would I correctly anchor the automation to click into the two cells below column C when the rows are changing each time the sheet is filtered.

I tried using the click function, and anchoring the click to the title of column C, then I tried running the automation without any anchor.

Comment: I dont think interacting with excel with UI activities is good idea. If you want to filter and get the data, why not to read data in datatable and then create filter to get the data. Can please explain more about what should be the end result of bot.

Comment: Exactly, just use clicking in Excel when everything else is not working. Usual read/write/filter is done with UiPath activities.

Answer (score 0):

is there any specific reason why you are not using Pivot table(for excel) or Query function(for google sheet)?

Based on the current description, I would suggest to skip the UIPath script itself, you can directly write small formula/pivot table achieve same result with better efficiency

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).